# How to make lines thinner one one or both ends in gimp

Tags: gimp

So I started playing with gimp not so long ago and I can't figure out how draw line which is thinner on one end or even both kinda I want it to look like pencil sharp end see image and you will understand what I'm asking. I would be very happy if anyone can explain how to do it, preferably with paths tool.

[image]

NOTE: I have only keyboard and mouse as input metods.

Comment: I wouldn't use GIMP to create an image like that.  Use Inkscape instead. It's free and open source, and It's a vector image editor, and it's designed to be used for those kind of images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a curve which has varying width altough in vector drawing programs also that is possible. It's a filled area.

In GIMP or Photoshop you can draw a closed path. Corner points are made by clicking and the nodes with tangent handles are made by dragging and holding the mouse button at the same time.

Node editing tools allow radical edits. You can insert and remove the nodes, move them and adjust the handles.

These are also essential skills in vector drawing software (Illustrator, Inkscape)

In bitmap editors (GIMP, Photoshop) you can define the path to be a clipping mask of a colored layer. As well you can convert it to a selection and fill the selected area with a color.

[image]

ADD: The following is much easier in vector drawing software. It's from Inkscape.

[image]

A horizontal triangle was drawn and copied to the clipboard. Then a couple of curves were drawn, their strokes were defined to be the content of the clipboard.

Vector drawing programs have quite usable tools for bending a shape along a path. In Illustrator and Affinity Designer it can even be a photo. Inkscape accepts only vector shapes.

**in GIMP**: There's already another answer. You can define simulated pressure dynamics which tapers the brush and stroke a path with it. Possible, but I see it complex.

You can also apply curve bend filter or cage transform. Even more complex, no way to apply a drawn path.

Of course a highly skilled painter could draw it with a real brush, even with a graphic tablet, but you had excluded those options.

Comment: Wow, this is much simpler than I have imagined, it does the thing, but there is catch if you need already thin line to become thinner it starts to become pain in the ass, so if it's possible to do it with brush/ using brush to stroke a path? If you can only point me in right direction I would be very thankfull, add to your answer please.

Comment: @BlackCloud updated the answer

Comment: Thanks once more, I guess in the end i will use inkscape for this kind of stuff. Gimp isn't playing nice with thin lines become thinner while thicker are fine to be done. I would upvote answer but I don't have enough points to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [brush dynamics](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-dynamics.html), with a "fade length" and set the dynamics to either start start small and become thicker as you go, or start thick and go thin (just invert the mapping curve, for SW->NE to NW->SE).

[image]

But you really want to use paths, or even something like InkScape.

Comment: Ahh, yeah I figured this but wasn't satisfied with result, so I guess I would have to use inkscape when paths don't play nice. Thanks